# Indexer Update by Schedule not Updating Indexer Related Cron Job

Tags: magento2

A few days back everything works well.

But suddenly other cron get run except indexer-related cron.

Nighter new code or feature get added not changes done on server.

Only changes happen some new products get added.

then found **indexer_update_all_views** showing running & not get executed.

**Executed stated ad 14:11:03, when I take the screenshot it read 20:00:55.**

[image]

On indexer, third-party indexer Cron job (Like Algolia)run well, but Magento code indexer not get run.

Any Idea??

Platfrom : Magento 2
Version : 2.2.7
Php Version: 7.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If a cronjob is stuck on "running", just delete the "running" cronjob from the database. Magento will run the next scheduled "indexer_update_all_views" job and when it runs, check if it has "success" status. If it also get's stuck in "running", then check the log files for any errors.